# What were the editions to the KJV since 1611 and who did them and when?

Tags: bible, kjv

So the King James Bible came out in 1611 with the authorized version, then in 1769 with the standard version.  Supposedly, there were some minor spelling corrections made in the late 1800's and in 1900.  Is there anything that documents these things?  Does anyone print the standard edition any more as it was in 1769?

Comment: Have you reviewed the relevant section of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#Printing)?  It lays out the highlights of the printing history from 1611 to today.  Are you looking for anything more specific?

Comment: Ive went there a few times, but I dont think I noticed the section on the 1769 edition.  Thanks for the prompt to go over it again.  Also of interest is the Oxford and Cambridge publishers.

Comment: "thou shalt commit adutlery" is not a 'minor spelling error' xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been minor updates by the publishers. Generally these are spelling updates, or changes to the punctuation. But there have been a lot. Each publisher generally changes something or other. Rick Norris has compiled a huge book on these, called "Facts from 400 Years of KJV Editions: Do We Use a 1769 KJV?"

You can also purchase fascimile 1769 Bibles (or 1611s) that are photocopies, so definitely with no revisions. Example: https://greatsite.com/facsimile-reproductions/1769.html